# Page display the All page Content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have display all page content in current page but **not current page content** to be display so bellow code give me all page content but how can i filter it ?

Thanks.

```
 $pages = get_pages(); 
 foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
  $title = $page_data->post_title; 
 echo $content; 
}
```

Comment: **Or** _use of specific parent page_ 'global $post;
      wp_list_pages(array('child_of'=>$post->post_parent,'depth' => 2,'exclude' => get_the_ID())); '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code: it will exclude the current page by taking its ID.

```
<?php                                   
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'numberposts' => -1,                                                                    
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
        'post_status' => 'publish',                 
        'exclude' => get_the_ID()
    );          
//$allpages = get_pages($args );  ?>
<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
```